# Entity Framework Remove. Why do I need to set the entity state?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I use the following code snippet to delete a parent Job record with child Design records.

```
 foreach (var item in data.Items.Where(i => i.DeletePending == true && i.ItemId > 0))
{
    var deljob = connect.job.Include(j => j.Design).Single(j => j.JobID == item.ItemId);
    foreach (var delDesign in deljob.Design.ToArray())   
    {
        // next line is needed or it fails
        connect.Entry(delDesign).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        deljob.xVivDesign.Remove(delDesign);
    }
    // no need to set the state here
    connect.job.Remove(deljob);
}
```

The error is

The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was removing the Design from the Job's collection of designs.  Instead I should have been removing the design from the Entity Set

Thus the answer was to use

```
connect.design.Remove(delDesign)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that there's a foreign key constraint that you would be violating by deleting that record.

If I have the following tables:

**Customer**

```
Id   | Name   | Age
---------------------
1    | Barry  | 52
```

**Order**

```
Id   | CustId   | OrderAmount
------------------------------
1    |   1      | 27.39
```

For this example, **Order** has a foreign key constraint on `Order.CustId = Customer.id`, I would not be able to delete *Barry* from my **Customer** table, unless I first deleted all references of *Barry* in the **Order** table because of the foreign key constraint (Anything in **Order** with a *custId* of 1)

As the error message explains,

> When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key
>   property is set to a null value.

By deleting *Barry* from **Customer**, you no longer have a record of **Customer** with an ID of 1.  This will violate the constraint, as it would try to set a non-nullable integer (*userId* in **Order**) to a null value.

I would suggest looking at [Foreign Key Constraints](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Assuming there are no other keys tied to the job you are trying to delete, you could delete the job entry after deleting all the design records associated with that job.  **Only do that if you are 100% confident that you will never need the design records again.**

Comment: thanks @silencedmessage. My confusuion was that I thought I was deleting the design records before the job record.  However removing from the collection is not the same as removing from the database.

Comment: Duely noted. Guess I jumped the gun a little.  Thanks for the feedback.